# Jdk 1.6.37 installation and setting up in fedora 17

Tags: java, fedora, sun-java6-jdk

I have installed jdk 1.6.37 in fedora 17 which already has java 1.7 openjdk i want to set java 1.6 as my default java how can i do this...

When i check the following command in terminal

```
                 alternatives --display java
```

the result does not list the jdk 1.6.37 but it actually installed and exist in /usr/java/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install alternatives :

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/bin/java 100
```

Then you can configure your java alternatives :

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

Let, `update-alternatives --config java` guide you.

Are you sure you want `jdk (java development kit)` instead of standart `jre (java runtime environment)` ?